# How to check a checkbox status inside a ListView on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I got on my code a listview with check boxes, but How can I check if the value of the checkbox?
I'm implementing a program with tabs, and one of the tabs has the ListView with checkboxes, the code is as follows:

```
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(OPTS_TAB_TAG).setIndicator("Options",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_options))
              .setContent(new TabContentFactory() 
              {
                public View createTabContent(String arg0) 
                {

                        DbAdapter databaseManager = new DbAdapter(BusTrackerBetaActivity.this);
                        databaseManager.open();

                        List<String> BusLinesList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        BusLinesList = databaseManager.toStringList(databaseManager.getAllBusLines(), 1);

                        String[] BusLinesArray = BusLinesList.toArray(new String[BusLinesList.size()]);


                    databaseManager.close();

                    ListView ls1 = new ListView(BusTrackerBetaActivity.this); 
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            BusTrackerBetaActivity.this, 
                         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                         BusLinesArray);
                     ls1.setAdapter(adapter); 
                     ls1.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(BusTrackerBetaActivity.this); 

                     ls1.setItemsCanFocus(false);
                     ls1.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                     return ls1;

                }

            });
```

It's working fine, acctually I got this way of implementing the list from some examples, but my question is: How can I check the value (true or false) of each checkbox?

Comment: Check this [A complete example of ListView with Checkbox](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ListView`'s `getCheckedItemPositions` function to accomplish this.  It will return a `SparseBooleanArray` object containing the checked status of each item in the ListView.  Loop through the `SparseBooleanArray` to determine which items are checked.

You will need to keep a reference to your `ListView` object somewhere so that you can easily access it later when you need to determine checked item status.

```
    SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = ls1.getCheckedItemPositions();
    if (checkedItems != null)
        for (int i = 0; i < checkedItems.size(); i++)
        {
            if (checkedItems.valueAt(i))
            {
                String s = ls1.getAdapter().getItem(checkedItems.keyAt(i)).toString();
                //s contains your checked item, checkedItems.keyAt(i) is the index of the checked item
            }

        }
```